# Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException at ImageResizerTest.java:50

Tags: flutter, gradlew, imagepicker

i'm trying to develop an app, but every time i run .gradlew build it fails giving the error: image_picker_android:testDebugUnitTest FAILED and Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException at ImageResizerTest.java:50.

my manifest.xml is:

```
"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.my_firstapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="food_track"
        android:icon="@drawable/launch_background">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.my_firstapp.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true">
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.aptreesoftware.barcodescan.BarcodeScannerActivity"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

i'm not understanding what does it mean

Comment: Did you fix this?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Nope, i'm sorry